# How do I recover an unregistered username?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I asked a question the other day as an unregistered user. There were some good answers to it. I then tried to register my username. The registration worked, kind of. I got an account by the same name, but it didn't import the couple of cred points, and it didn't give me back control over my previous question. I can't give the guy who answered correctly the credit he deserves.

So 1) is there a way to connect my now registered account with the old unregistered one

and barring that 2) is there a way to log back into the unregistered account? There wasn't a password. There was just a cookie that was wiped out when I registered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I merged your accounts together, so your registered account has [your previously asked question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53154/how-do-i-cycle-through-panes-inside-a-window-in-tmux-like-in-screen) now

For future reference if other people have this problem, it's possible to recover your cookie using the [account recovery page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery), and once you're logged back in to the unregistered account you can add an OpenID to register it

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you very much!